# C #: Passing dynamic Type in Generic gives error targetType is a variable but is used like a type

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, dynamic, types

```
Type propertyType = nestedProperty.PropertyType;

var targetType = IsNullableType(propertyType) ? 
     Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType) : propertyType;

GetPredicateTemp'<'T , targetType> ("storage");
```

Here on passing targetType giving error targetType is a variable but is used like a type.
targettype returns Int64
how can I pass this type , I need to return the lambda expression of this type only.

my question is different.. Here see the method, I need to pass two types T1,T2..In place of **T2** , want to pass **targetType**

~ public static Expression`<Func<T1, T2>> GetPredicateTemp<T1, T2>(string propName)`where T1 : UserEntity
        {

```
        string[] props = propName.Split('.');
        Type t1 = typeof(T1);
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = t1.GetProperty(props[0]);
        PropertyInfo nestedProperty = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetProperty(props[1]);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t");
        MemberExpression expBody = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo.Name);
        expBody = Expression.Property(expBody, nestedProperty.Name);
        var predicateNEW = Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2>>(expBody, new ParameterExpression[] { parameter });
        return predicateNEW;
    }
```

Comment: Edit your question, clear the code, copy and paste it in fresh. Then highlight the code block and hit the `{}` button to format it as a code block

Comment: `targetType` is a variable, but you are using it as a type name

Comment: how can I pass two types T1,T2 in generic while calling the function?   T2 should be of targetType

Comment: Problem solved by using **object** type as second parameter as below                                                                                                                                       
  Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(expBody, typeof(object));  
  Expression<Func<T, object>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conversion, new ParameterExpression[] { parameter });